# Совместимость SQLAlchemy-Utils с SQLAlchemy 1.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, sqlalchemy

Возникает ошибка при запуске тестов. Погуглив ошибку - видел, что с версии `SQLAlchemy-Utils==0.37.0` починили совместимость с алхимией 1.4, но почему то проблема несовместимости все же присутствует. Использую в проекте `SQLAlchemy-Utils==0.37.9` и `SQLAlchemy==1.4.26`. Пробовал опускать ниже версии библиотек - не помогает.
Сама ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете временно исправить это, изменив импорт в
sqlalchemy_utils\functions\orm.py:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.query import _ColumnEntity
```

НА:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.context import _ColumnEntity
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Судя по последнему посту на скрине, все еще нет полноценной поддержки.